# failed to retrieve value of a variable defined inside render function in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

In my code I am trying to retrieve location name from latitide and longitude positions using geocode reducer and trying to display it.

this is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import { compose, withProps,withHandlers,lifecycle } from "recompose"
import { withScriptjs, withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Marker,InfoWindow } from "react-google-maps"
import { MarkerClusterer } from 'react-google-maps/lib/components/addons/MarkerClusterer';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


export default class DemoApp extends React.Component {
    render() {
        var areaName,locName;
        const MyMapComponent = compose(
            withProps({
                googleMapURL: ('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places&key=AIzaSyAoaDS6fIKlYvEHeTaakCxXqp-UwnggoEg'),
                loadingElement: (<div style={{ height: '100%' }} />),
                containerElement: (<div style={{ height: '400px' }} />),
                mapElement: (<div style={{ height: '100%' }} />)
            }),
            withScriptjs,
            withGoogleMap,
            lifecycle({
                componentWillMount() {

                    let geocoder = new window.google.maps.Geocoder();
                    geocoder.geocode( { 'latLng': {lat:this.props.newMap.lat,lng:this.props.newMap.lng}}, function(results, status) {
                        if (status == 'OK') {
                            console.log('here result of geocoder', results);
                            if (results[0]) {
                                let adrs_comp = results[0].address_components;
                                for(let  i = 0; i < adrs_comp.length; i++) {
                                    if(adrs_comp[i].types[0] === "locality" ) {
                                        locName = adrs_comp[i].long_name;
                                        console.log("loc name");
                                        console.log(locName);
                                        console.log("loc name");
                                    }
                                    if(adrs_comp[i].types[0] === "administrative_area_level_1" ) {
                                        areaName = adrs_comp[i].long_name;
                                        console.log("area name");
                                        console.log(areaName);
                                        console.log("area name");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            console.log('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
                        }
                    });
                }
            })
        )(props =>{
            return (<GoogleMap
                zoom={this.props.myMap.zoom}
                center={{lat:this.props.myMap.lat, lng:this.props.myMap.lng}}
            >
             <Marker
          position={{lat:this.props.myMap.lat, lng:this.props.myMap.lng }} >
          <InfoWindow>
            <p>{locName}</p>
          </InfoWindow>
          </Marker>
            </GoogleMap>)
        }
        );

        return(
            <MyMapComponent newMap={this.props.myMap} />
        );
    }
}
```

In the above code how can I display the value of locname variable in the info window of google map?.I think it's because of the google map component only received props as parameter.How to solve this issue?

Comment: Please, provide a Codesandbox example, or similar service

Comment: You can pass area name and location as props to the component like
 `withProps({
                googleMapURL: ('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places&key=AIzaSyAoaDS6fIKlYvEHeTaakCxXqp-UwnggoEg'),
                loadingElement: (<div style={{ height: '100%' }} />),
                containerElement: (<div style={{ height: '400px' }} />),
                mapElement: (<div style={{ height: '100%' }} />)
                areaName,
                locName
            }),`

Comment: @ Shubham Khatri how to retrieve the locname in the google map component?i just passed the parameters in the 'withprops' property.How can i retrieve it in      `(props =>{
        console.log(locName);
        return(
            <GoogleMap
                zoom={this.props.myMap.zoom}
                center={{lat:this.props.myMap.lat, lng:this.props.myMap.lng}}
            >`